# Check author of referenced node if the same as acting author in Drupal Rules module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a node type (A) that is referenced by another node type (B). I want it so that every time node type B is created, the author of node type A is notified. I can set up a rule with Rules module with this setting:

```
DO
action Load a referenced node
action Load the author of the node
action Send a mail to a user
```

But now I also want to check if the author of node B is the same as author of node A. If it is the same, I do not want to send an email. Is there a way to do this with Rules?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can compare users in conditions.

Comment: yes, but it can't compare the acting user with the author of the referenced node.